# How does the inverse limit glue together sections on a basis?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, category-theory, sheaf-theory

I am referring to this claim from Görtz and Wedhorn, page 49:

[image]

I get the intuition provided by the paragraph, but I absolutely do not get how this intuition is satisfied by the inverse limit. Intuitively I want to define $\mathscr{F}(V)$ using something involving intersections and disjoint unions. Perhaps I am missing an unstated isomorphism here, but how can it be the case that the section of $\mathscr{F}$ on $V$ is composed of *tuples* of sections on $U \in \mathcal{B}$? Excuse my inner programmer, but there seems to be a type mismatch here.

Also, what is the point of requiring $s_U \mid _{U'} = s_{U'}$? Is it just the "most universal" way to extract sections that agree on $V$?

Comment: The sheaf property says: "any collection of sections over open subsets that glue correctly give a global section on what such open subsets cover". A generic element of the inverse limit is precisely a collection of sections over open subsets that glue correctly.

Comment: @PedroTamaroff  Isn't an element of the inverse limit a *product* of sections? How can that be treated as a section?

Comment: @SimonKuang it is somewhat misleading to think of $(s_U)_U$ as a product of sections as opposed to a tuple of sections satisfying the stated coherence condition, if that makes sense. The "type mismatch" is somewhat resolved by the definition of a limit/colimit, whose elements are defined (set theoretically at least) by imposing an equivalence relation...

Comment: ...I make this distinction because the point is not to look at all of the entries in $(s_U)_U$ all the time; rather, the entries give enough information to answer any given question about the values of your sheaf over the set $V$; for example, if you want to compute the stalk at $p \in V$, you just look at those entries in the tuple whose $U$ contains $p$.

Comment: @TabesBridges So the construction doesn't give the section "exactly" but only "up to direct limit"?

Comment: @SimonKuang Not exactly... Have you looked at example A.3 on p. 544? This gives the concrete construction in the category of sets, and basic algebraic categories.

Comment: @TabesBridges I think I understand what inverse limits do in general. I just don't connect that to how they perform this function of gluing sections. I follow the discussion on how they carry information, I just don't see how the given $\mathscr{F}$ delivers on what you expect from $\mathscr{F}$—for example, let $V = X$ and let $\mathscr{f}$ be continuous functions to $\mathbb{R}$. Then the section over $V$ by this statement is the product of the sections over all of $\mathcal{B}$. But is a tuple in this product a function $X\to\mathbb{R}$? How can this be?

Comment: @SimonKuang Yes, because although you have this big product, the actual value of a section a point $p$ can be computed by looking at the values over those $U \in \mathcal{B}$ which contain $p$. Computing the value at this point amounts to computing the (ordinary calculus/analysis) limit as you approach $p$ in any direction, and these values will be independent of the particular opens that you actually looked at. Keep in mind that there is a LOT of information in this big tuple, but it is also wildly overdetermined (since any given point is contained in many basic opens).

Comment: @SimonKuang I guess it would be accurate to say that the tuple is not *literally* a section, but it induces a unique section over $V$ which restricts to the given sections.

Answer (score 0):

In terms of your basis $\mathcal{B}$ you cannot express the gluing
condition as $s_U|_{U\cap V}=s_V|_{U\cap V}$ since $U\cap V$
may not be a basis element whenever $U$ and $V$ are. But $U\cap V$
is a union of basis elements, so we can replace that by
$s_U|_{W}=s_V|_{W}$ where $W$ runs through the basis elements $\subseteq U\cap V$. But a particular case of this is $s_U|_W=s_W|_W=s_W$.
So the gluing condition is equivalent to $s_U|_W=s_W$
for all basis elements $U\supseteq W$.

We can regard $\mathcal{B}$ as a poset, and so a category and $U\mapsto
\mathscr{F}(U)$ as a functor from $\mathcal B$ to $\mathbf{Ab}$.
From the description of inverse limits of inverse
systems of Abelian one get the authors' equality.

Comment: What if $V$ is covered by $\mathcal{B}$ but does not contain any $U \in \mathcal{B}$?